# Query that needs input from two different records

Tags: libreoffice, query, libreoffice-base

I have a "timecard" table.  A few typical entries might look like

```
ID   task            date       start time
1    proj_XDFR       4/5/18     8:30
2    proj_PEIRN      4/5/18     9:45
3    proj_ERU54      4/5/18     10:30
4    lunch           4/5/18     11:30
```

etc.

So, I want a query that can calculate the timespan between tasks.  For example, the time spent on `proj_XDFR` was 9:45 - 8:30 = 1:15.  All of the queries I am familiar with use data within a single record.  Here I need one that can access data from succeeding records.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks.  (P.S. No time span is going to cross a date boundary, so that is not a worry.)

EDIT: Just to be clear, this is a problem I am having in Base, the database program, not in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

In the spreadsheet *8:30* would be at D2 and *9:45* at D3. create a another column called **time taken**, column E. then in cell E2 type **=D3-D2**, in my test i get *01:15:00*. simply copy E2 and paste in to E3, it automatically adjusts the cell numbering.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a problem I am having with the database, not the spreadsheet.